# simple way to create multiple flash message in laravel-9

Tags: php, laravel-9

is there any way to simplify these three line to create multiple flash message?

```
session()->flash('status', 'error');
session()->flash('title', 'test title');
session()->flash('message', 'test message');
```

i tried this but does not work

```
return view('panel.codes.CodeCrud.create', [
   'categories' => collect(),
   'cards' => collect(),
])->with([
   'status' => 'error',
   'title' => 'test title',
   'message' => 'test message',
]);
```

Comment: Use multi dimen array.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array as a second argument to session()->flash

```
session()->flash('status', ['status' => 'error', 'title' => 'test title']);
```

Comment: How do you read them in the Blade? And what if for the same `status` there are two different `title`?

Comment: @burf use different keys or nested array for title. read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#raw-php and  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#the-global-session-helper

Answer (score -1):

You can use session() helper and merge array and pass it

```
session([
    'status'    =>  'error',
    'title'     =>  'test title',
    'message'   =>  'test message'
])
```